# How to batch rename vertex groups

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-groups

I am working on a rigify rig, but made the mistake of setting up the weights before generating the rig, so all the vertex group names correspond to bones on the metarig. Is there an easy way to quickly add the DEF- prefix to all the vertex groups so I don't have to manually go through all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

You can execute it from the Python Console

```
for i in bpy.context.active_object.vertex_groups:
    oldn=i.name
    i.name='DEF-'+oldn
```

Cheers,